# PHP Image String Color is not proper

Tags: php, image, php-gd

I Have Install a PHP-GD Library and do several code for the birthday wishes.
But i get one problem over there

```
<?php    
$path="birthday-images/birthday.png";
    $string = "Rohit P Vakharia (February 4th)";
    $font = 'ambient.ttf';
    $s='birthday-raw/birthday'. 4 .'.png';  //Image Number for different Images
    $im= imagecreatefrompng($s);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $counter=1;
    imagettftext($im,40 , 0, 80, 500, $white, $font, $string);
    imagettftext($im,40 , 0, 80, 625, $white, $font, $string);
    imagepng($im,$path);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I have run the same code for two different images. now My problem is in one image i get the string with white color (IN Yellow Image) and In Another I get the String with Blue (IN BLUE Image).

> I want that both image have same **white color string**

Please give me Suggestion what should i do for this.

For Reference i have attached several images here.

[image: Raw Image-1]
**Raw Birthday Image -1**

[image: After Proccessing Img-1]
**After Script Run The Img With White Font**

[image: Raw IMG -2] 
**Raw Birthday Image -2**

[image: After Proccessing IMG-2]
**After Script Run The Img With Blue Font**

Comment: Check what is exactly returned by `imagecolorallocate`.

Comment: @Seti i have check the value of the `imagecolorallocate` is returns null, and i give the value of 255 but it is not gives white color

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php 

please use `var_dump($white);` to know the value and variable type.

Comment: it is  int type for first image and for second image it is Boolean type.

Comment: And probably boolean FALSE right? If yes - then it coudlnt allocate that.

Comment: @Seti, I have found the solution for this, i have to install the library called  freeType `sudo apt-get install freetype*` using this command and the font should be `'./ambient.ttf' <-- Added ./ ` so now i can see the effect. Thank you for your support.  : )